# Julian date conversion error in an RPG program

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpg

I have below RPG code which results in a runtime error when trying to convert the julian date value 2041085. whereas the value 2021085 works successfully.

Can someone please guide what might be wrong?

```
D EMPDAT          S              6  0              
                                                   
                                                   
                                                   
  empdat = %dec(%date(2021085:*longjul):*mdy);     
  empdat = %dec(%date(2041085:*longjul):*mdy);
```

Comment: It seems `*cmdy` goes until 2899, does that work instead of `*mdy`?

Comment: thank you!! I can work with this and modify it a bit to get the date I want.

Comment: Instead of editing your old question to ask something else, please create a brand-new question.

Answer (score 2):

Use 4 digit years for all dates. Like This:

```
D EMPDAT          S              8  0                                                             
                                               
  empdat = %dec(%date(2021085:*longjul):*usa);     
  empdat = %dec(%date(2041085:*longjul):*usa);
```

Or better, just use date fields. You can do date arithmetic with them, and also compare them (which you can't do properly with *usa or *mdy format).

```
D EMPDAT          S               D
                                               
  empdat = %date(2021085:*longjul);     
  empdat = %date(2041085:*longjul);
```

Comment: Hi Murph, my ultimate aim is to convert this into mmddyy format. Can you tell me how this can be done?

Comment: *usa is mmddyyyy. You can't have the year 2041 in mmddyy format without manual intervention, and all the date functions will treat it as 1941.